# Paperclip error uploading file through Rails API using Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, faraday

I'm trying to upload a file to my controller via an api call from another app. I'm using Faraday to make the post request but I'm getting this error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "#<UploadIO:0x007fb3ba8391c0>"):
app/controllers/talks_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

This is my faraday request:

```
puts conn.post "/talks.json", { talk: { title: 'asdf8', link: 'fakelink', audio: Faraday::UploadIO.new('dhh-37signals.mp3', 'audio/mp3') }}
```

And this is my model:

```
class Talk < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :link, presence: true
  has_attached_file :audio
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :audio
end
```

I think it has something to do with paperclip only seeing this `#<UploadIO:0x007fb3ba8391c0>"` as my uploaded file and not my actual file. When I upload a file through my form in my view it works fine, but uploading through Faraday isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: How was this solved ? Did you solve it ? I am facing this now